# IBM gpfs 4.2.1 compile error

Tags: linux, filesystems

I encountered the following error while I was compiling gpfs.

OS:RHEL7.4
GPFS:4.2.1

1.# cd /usr/lpp/mmfs/src/

2.# make LINUX_DISTRIBUTION=REDHAT_AS_LINUX Autoconfig

3.# make World

When the third step occurs, the following error occurs。

```
DVERBOSETRACE  -DLROC   -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR()" -fno-stack-protector -Wformat=0 -Wno-format-security -I/usr/lpp/mmfs/src/gpl-linux -c kdump.c 
cc kdump.o kdump-kern.o kdump-kern-dwarfs.o -o kdump     -lpthread
kdump-kern.o: In function `GetOffset':
kdump-kern.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `page_offset_base'
kdump-kern.o: In function `KernInit':
kdump-kern.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `page_offset_base'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/lpp/mmfs/src/gpl-linux'
make: *** [Modules] Error 1
```

Answer (score 6):

add `unsigned long page_offset_base;` on top of the file /usr/lpp/mmfs/src/gpl-linux/kdump.c

Answer (score 0):

i see the same problem compiling with the kernel (3.10.0-693.1.1.el7.x86_64).  (rhel7.3 updated + GPFS 4.2.3-1)

I resolved it using a previous kernel: kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64

I hope this help.

Regards